# How to add header bar when using createBottomTabNavigator?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to add a constant Header bar to my screen (all screens, [similar to this example](https://www.google.com/search?q=react%20native%20header%20example&client=firefox-b-1-ab&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgo7CzueveAhXqiFQKHdP0A2YQ_AUIDigB&biw=1440&bih=782#imgrc=j7TExcYiin8GLM:)) with basic functionality (menu button, and a back button), but I'm having trouble finding a way to do this when using `createBottomTabNavigator`. I haven't seen anything saying this isn't possible, so if I'm making a design mistake, do let me know.

Here is my minimal foobar example (it runs):

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';


class ScreenA extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        screenName: 'Screen A'
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <View 
          style={styles.container}
        >
          <Text>{this.state.screenName}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
};

class ScreenB extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        screenName: 'Screen B'
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <View 
          style={styles.container}
        >
          <Text>{this.state.screenName}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
};


const BottomTabNav = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    ScreenA: {
      screen: ScreenA,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: '',
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
          return <Ionicons
                    name={ focused ? 'ios-card' : 'ios-card-outline' }
                    size={30}
                    style={{ marginTop: 6 }}
                 />;
        },
      }
    },
    ScreenB: {
      screen: ScreenB, 
      navigationOptions: {
        title: '',
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
          return <Ionicons
                    name={ focused ? 'ios-chatbubbles' : 'ios-chatbubbles-outline' }
                    size={30}
                    style={{ marginTop: 6 }}
                 />;
        },
      },
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'ScreenA',
  }
);


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BottomTabNav />
    );
  }
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

Apologies for not including a Snack link, but I'm having issues with dependencies when trying to build the demo.

Comment: you probably want all your screens in the tab navigator (ScreenA, ScreenB) to be Stack  navigators, eg. you'd say `const ScreenA = createStackNavigator(...)`

Answer (score 4):

You need your screens to be stack navigators which you then can add in your tab navigator. The "defaultNavigationOptions" are your navigationOptions for the header and the navigationOptions in the code snippet corresponds for the BottomTabNavigator options.

You can read more about this here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html

```
const StackA = createStackNavigator({ ScreenA },
{
  defaultNavigationOptions: (navigationOptions),
  navigationOptions: {
    tabBarLabel: 'Screen A',
  },
});

const StackB = createStackNavigator({ScreenA},
{
  defaultNavigationOptions: (navigationOptions),
  navigationOptions: {
    tabBarLabel: 'Screen B',
  },
});

const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({StackA, StackB});
```

Answer (score 0):

only `createStackNavigator` has its own header so you have to wrap whatever you want in it, according to your question there is two answers to this,

1. put the `createBottomTabNaviagator` in a parent `createStackNavigator` and access the `createBottomTabNavigator` children `routeName` and assign it to the parent `createStackNavigator` header

```js
const BottomTabNav = createBottomTabNavigator({
  FirstScreen: ScreenA,
  SecondScreen: ScreenB,
});

BottomTabNav.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  // By default routeName will come from the BottomTabNav,
  // but here we can access the children screens 
  // and give the parent ParentStack that routeName
  const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];

  // You can do whatever you like here to pick the title based on the route name
  const headerTitle = routeName;

  return {
    headerTitle,
  };
};

const ParentStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: BottomTabNav,
  AnotherScreen: AnotherScreen,
});
```

2. put the child screens in a `createStackNavigator` so that every child will have its own header

```js
const ScreenA = createStackNavigator({
  FirstScreen: ScreenA,
  /* other routes here */
});

const ScreenB = createStackNavigator({
  SecondScreen: ScreenB,
  /* other routes here */
});

const BottomTabNav = createBottomTabNavigator({
  FirstScreen: ScreenA,
  SecondScreen: ScreenB,
});
```